# How to load different pages in O365 mail app based on regex

Tags: javascript, office365, office365-apps, office-js

I am creating an O365 app and I have 2 .aspx files, when the user clicks on the O365 mail app, I want each of these pages to be loaded based on the subject of the mail.

Scenario 1: Mail subject contains '#'
result: load page1

Scenario 2: Mail subject does not contain '#'
result: load page2

I have tried having an intermediate .js file where I have written the logic,
but when I do window.location = "path_to_aspx_file", 
only the html is loaded but the js files do not run.

My current implementation:

I have LandingLogic.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

     //The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var item = Office.cast.item.toItemRead(Office.context.mailbox.item);
            var sub = item.subject;
            if (sub.indexOf("some text") > -1) {                                
                window.location = "http://localhost:51776/File1.aspx";
            }
            else {
                window.location = "http://localhost:51776/File2.aspx";
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

After a bit of fumbling around.
I am able to navigate to each of these files now, but I am not sure how to access the mail subject from File1.aspx and File2.aspx.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "when I do window.load = "path_to_aspx_file", only the html is loaded but the js files do not run"? It seems like you are on the right track, but I have no clue what the issue you are running into is.

Comment: Are you talking about an app using the Graph API or an Outlook Add-in?

Comment: @MrPiao: Apologies for the typo, I am using window.location = "path_to_aspx file", I have added more details to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the Office context before you using Office JavaScript API to get the subject? To redirect the HTML page easily, we can include the JavaScript like below:

Home.js:

```
/// <reference path="../App.js" />

(function () {
    "use strict";

// The Office initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();

        RedirectHTMLPage();
    });
};

function RedirectHTMLPage() {
    var subject = Office.context.mailbox.item.subject;
    if (subject.indexOf("#") != -1) {
        window.location.href = "https://localhost:44300/page1.aspx";


    } else {
        window.location.href = "https://localhost:44300/page2.aspx";

    }

}

})();
```

The HTML page for redirecting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<title></title>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Content/Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- To enable offline debugging using a local reference to Office.js, use:                        -->
<!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->
<!-- <script src="../../Scripts/Office/1/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  -->

<link href="../App.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

> > I have tried having an intermediate .js file where I have written the logic, but when I do window.load = "path_to_aspx_file", only the html is loaded but the js files do not run.

Would you mind sharing the detail you using the “window.load”?

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, I am using window.location.

I have a similar implementation now, could you tell me how I can access the mail subject from page1.aspx and page2.aspx now?

Answer (score 0):

Fei Xue answer is correct . if you want to get subject from file2.aspx , add office.js reference and access subject same as file1.aspx inside the Office.initialize event

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```